# How to embed a .ppsx file into an HTML?

Tags: embed, powerpoint

What is the best way to embed a .ppsx (a powerpoint extension) on a webpage? I tried Google Docs but it's currently unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

"Best" would depend on what you're after, but this explains a nice simple way of going about it that costs nothing and doesn't require that the end user have PowerPoint installed:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/solutions/powerpoint-embed.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a shortcut (.lnk) and then link to the the shortcut, not the file directly.
Not perfect, but close.